# React dont render null values in cell using string literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont want to render null for address2 and address3 if the user has not input a value. Could anyone tell me a good day of doing it.
Thanks

```
result.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
       <TableCell align="center">
           {`${row.address1} ${row.address2} ${row.address3}`}
       </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is no reason to render a templating string inside a templating language. Why not use the templating language to your advantage, [JSX already hides render output if `null` is returned](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering).

Applying the above something like this would do the trick:

```
<TableCell align="center">
    {row.address1} {row.address2} {row.address3}
</TableCell>
```

This will leave 2 spaces between address 1 and 3 if 2 is not present. However HTML collapses adjacent whitespace into a single space, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: _JSX already hides render output if null is returned_ - why didn't i think of this :P ... +1.

Comment: This is the same that answered @miquel-las-heras but removing the `{" "}` as you suggested him in your comment. Even this way is more clean and compact, it is against ESLint react/jsx-one-expression-per-line rule (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-one-expression-per-line.md)

Comment: @VirgilioGM Not everybody uses the same lint rules. If you use `eslint-plugin-react`  with for example the [`react/recommended`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react#recommended) preset this rule is not enabled.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good way could be to keep addresses in an array that you can filter and join like this:

```js
{
  result.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
      <TableCell align="center">
        {[row.address1, row.address2, row.address3].filter(i => i).join(' ')}
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly writing each property in an array, you could use `Object.values(row).filter(i => i).join(' ')`

Comment: This assumes that you want to display every property value or that there is no other field but the three address

Comment: true but if `row` object only contains addresses, then `Object.values(row)` is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the variables are set and render them accordingly:

```js
result.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
       <TableCell align="center">
           {`${row.address1}${row.address2 ? " " + row.address2 : ""}${row.address3 ? " " + row.address3 : ""}`}
       </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
result.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
       <TableCell align="center">
         {row.address1}
         {" "}
         {row.address2}
         {" "}
         {row.address3}
       </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: You could just remove the `{" "}` parts and use `{row.address1} {row.address2} {row.address3}` there is already a literal space between them.

Comment: yes that can work, is a matter of preference. I prefer to be specific with spaces, looks cleaner to me and avoid possible issues with prettifiers

Comment: And this way complies the ESLint react/jsx-one-expression-per-line rule (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-one-expression-per-line.md)